# Use array to lessen code, but it doesn't appear as it should be in html php?

Tags: php, html, arrays

What did I do wrong? The first two show up OK, but the third one, ear nose throat had problem.

```
<?php
        $arr = Array('heart'=>'heart', 'eye'=>'eye', 'earnosethroat'=>'ear nose throat');

        foreach ($arr as $key=>$keys)

                {
                ?>                  
            <div class="disease_li" id="disease_li_<?php echo $arr[$key];?>">
                <span class="disease_menu_d" id="<?php echo $arr[$key];?>_disease"><?php echo $arr[$keys];?></span>
                <span class="disease_span" id="<?php echo $arr[$key];?>_1"><label>(<?php echo $arr[$keys];?>)</label>symptoms</span>
                <span class="disease_span" id="<?php echo $arr[$key];?>_2"><label>(<?php echo $arr[$keys];?>)</label>diseases</span>
            </div>          
    <?php
}?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're badly mis-using the foreach and key/value business.

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
                        ^^^^^---choose a better than than "keys".
   <span class="disease_menu_d" id="<?php $key;?>_disease"><?php $value;?></span>
etc...
```

Note the lack of `$arr[$key]` and `$arr[$keys]` inside the loop...

`$arr[$keys]` makes absolutely no sense. `$keys`, as created by `foreach()` is a **VALUE** in your array. it is not a key, and while PHP will happily let you use it as a key, you'll just get "undefined index", or a completely wrong value if that key happens to really exist.

Comment: Thanks you very much! by the way,  how come the first two show up OK!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use $arr[$key] and $arr[$keys] to access the array keys and values. In fact, $key and $keys are already contain key and value information in your array

```
<span class="disease_menu_d" id="<?php echo $key;?>_disease"><?php echo $keys;?></span>
```